# Calling putchar using x64 assembly through C++

Tags: c++, assembly

So, I wrote a little library that allows me to execute raw bytecode, as in assembly instructions, in C++.

I thought writing a brainfuck-to-x64 compiler with it. Everything worked, until I had to implement the `.` brainfuck instruction, which prints a character to stdout.

I know I need to pass the (only) argument through `rcx` (according to cdecl). But I don't know how to setup the stack, or cleanup after a function call. My ASM code is as follows:

```
push    rbp                             ; This is the only thing I tried doing as an epilog
mov     rcx,    QWORD PTR [rbx+rax*4]   ; rbx contains the address of an array (32-bit elements), and rax contains the index, the character byte is saved in that address
push    rax                             ; Retrieve rax after it gets clobbered by putchar
push    rcx                             ; Push rcx to use it as an argument
call    r10                             ; r10 contains the address of putchar
pop     rcx                             ; Restore all clobbered registers
pop     rax
pop     rbp
```

This snippet of code works, a character gets put into stdout, but after that, I just get "`Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.`"

What am I missing?
Sounds like putchar is not returning correctly due to `rsp` being corrupted, or something

By the way, I got the address of putchar like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
uint_least64_t putchar_addr = (uint_least64_t)&std::putchar;
```

I need to get the pointer as an integer so I can append it to the code buffer as bytecode later.

Comment: You do have a `ret` or something at the end, right? Also you did not set up shadow space properly, that might corrupt your saved registers. Not to mention that `putchar` may corrupt waaaaay more than the two registers you saved so depending on what you need that could be a problem.

Comment: yeah, I do `ret`, but thats at the end of the generated function, that code up there may be followed by more code.
I did read something about shadow space on the stack, how would I setup that?

Comment: `sub rsp, 32` or `40` before the `call` depending on your current stack pointer alignment status. Of course you need to free that later.